# How to implement cursor functionality using div as google does

Tags: jquery

I am using chromium browser in my project and for the text fields for my url, it is not showing blinking cursor. I tried to load the google.com and it worked. I figured out google uses their own cursor in the form of div. But couldn't replicate their solution. If anyone could help, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

```
<div style="background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 1px; z-index: 4; white-space: pre; width: 1px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 3px; display: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; "></div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about `contenteditable`? If you could post google's code it would be helpful. I'm not really sure what you are talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2d3/

Comment: If you load the google.com in mozilla and use firebug add-on you will come to know google uses div of size: 1px(width) 20px(height) as blinking cursor.

Comment: I see no such thing. Tested chrome, ff7 and ff10. They use an input field.

Comment: they use input field for text.but the cursor which blinks is nothing but a div..

Comment: @mrtsherman - No, google.com actually does use a blinking DIV for the cursor (you can check it firebug or even in chrome dev tools console). Why on earth they did it that way, only they would know..

Comment: @techfoobar - ahh, I finally found it. Wish OP had included the markup. Would have made it a lot easier to find.

Comment: Adding a bit more detail into the question would save time for people who are trying to find out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle for chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/xEVSu/2/

---

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/xEVSu/

What I've done is implement a custom blinking DIV for cursor that behaves like a normal cursor - i.e. moves with text typing, selection changes etc.. Also implemented is a custom highlight DIV (for text selection). Was fun implementing it, i must say! :)

***NOTE***: Unless you have a very good reason to be going for a custom implementation, use the default browser provided textbox functionality.

Comment: Yes, very little testing done on it. Very likely to have some flaws.. :) But i hope it leads the OP in the right direction..

Comment: It's a great solution. +1 from me as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well here is how I would do it even though I can't see what you are talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/pP3zk/

css

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 1px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

jquery

```
function blink() {
    $('div').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(blink);
    });
}

blink();
```

Comment: Getting the DIV to blink is the easy part. The difficult part is accurately positioning it according to the actual cursor movement.